# InfluxDB: In a query result, why does the "values" key have its values nested in an array?

Tags: influxdb

I have some data stored in InfluxDB. Here are two queries with their results:

```
http://influxdb.server/query?u=test&p=test&db=sensors&q=SELECT * FROM /^dwd\..*\.zehn-minuten\.niederschlag/ GROUP BY * ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1
{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[
  {"name":"dwd.str.schnarrenberg.zehn-minuten.niederschlag","columns":["time","QN","RWS_10","RWS_DAU_10","RWS_IND_10"],"values":[["2017-12-10T23:50:00Z",2,0,5,1]]},
  {"name":"dwd.str.flughafen.zehn-minuten.niederschlag","columns":["time","QN","RWS_10","RWS_DAU_10","RWS_IND_10"],"values":[["2017-12-10T23:50:00Z",2,0,0,0]]}
]}]}
```

Both contain the following segment

`"values":[[..., ..., ...]]`

What is the reason for nesting the values in an array?

Also, why are the results wrapped in an array?

`"results":[{`